# Parsing integer bit-patterns as IEEE 754 floats in dart

Tags: dart, floating-point, ieee-754, type-punning

I am getting 4 bytes of data through an interface(Bluetooth, List). The data is representing IEEE 754 float (e.g. `0x3fd0a3d7`, which represents approximately `1.63` as a binary32 `float`)

Is there a way in dart lang to convert / type-pun this to float and then double? Something like `intBitsToFloat` in Java. Couldn't find anything. Or do I just have to write the IEEE 754 parsing myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is working, just import the `dart:typed_data` library:

```
  var bdata = ByteData(4);
  bdata.setInt32(0, 0x3fd0a3d7);
  print(bdata.getFloat32(0)); //Prints: 1.6299999952316284
```

(I'm not sure this is the most reliable way)

Comment: I think it is currently the most reliable way to convert between the representtions of integers and floats: To store the representation of one into bytes and read it back as the other.

Comment: Nice, thanks. Can't believe I didn't find this after one hour of googling.