# Is there a Dart function to convert List<int> to Double?

Tags: dart, bluetooth, ieee-754

I'm getting a Bluetooth Characteristic from a Bluetooth controller with [flutter blue](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_blue/latest/flutter_blue/BluetoothCharacteristic-class.html) as a List. This characteristic contains weight measurement of a Bluetooth scale. Is there a function to convert this list of ints to a Double?

I tried to find some background on float representations by reading the IEEE 754 standard. There is the dart library typed_data but I am new to dart and have no experience with this lib.

Example:

I have this List: [191, 100, 29, 173] which is coming from a bluetooth controller as a IEEE754 representation for a float value. 
Now i believe i have to convert each int to hex and concat these values: `bf 64 1d ad`

Next thing need to do is convert this to double, but i cannot find a function to convert hex to double. Only `int.parse("0xbf641dad")`.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you have and what your want. I am not entirely sure about "Is there a function to convert this list of ints to a Float". I am reading this as you want to convert the list into a single Float value. But I need an example to be sure.

Comment: This basically answers my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55355482/parsing-integer-bit-patterns-as-ieee-754-floats-in-dart

Answer (score 6):

I guess your mean to convert the list of ints to a **list** of floats, not to a single float, right?
First, dart has no type called `float`. Instead it has type `double`. To convert it, you can use the `map()` function:

```
var listInt = [1, 2, 3];
var listDouble = list.map((i) => i.toDouble()).toList();
```

Answer (score 5):

Had this same issue.

I think you mean how do you make the four bytes into a float32 ?
I needed to do the same thing.

you will want to do something like this:

first take the List value as a byte buffer, then take the byte data, then you can use the getFloat32 function.

```
ByteBuffer buffer = new Int8List.fromList(value_in).buffer;
ByteData byteData = new ByteData.view(buffer);
result = byteData.getFloat32(0);
```

Just be a little aware that the order of bytes from the Bluetooth may be back to front, as the convention varys.

Also you will need the typed_data library:

```
import 'dart:typed_data'; //for data formatting
```

I'm trying to go in the other direction now . . . for the obvious reason.

Answer (score 2):

You may need this:

```
double parseHexString(String hexStr,  bool littleEndian){
  if(hexStr.length % 2 != 0){
    return 0;
  }
  if(littleEndian == true){
    List<int> bytes = hex.decode(hexStr).reversed.toList();
    hexStr = hex.encode(bytes);
  }
  var byteConvert = ByteData(12);
  byteConvert.setInt64(0, int.parse(hexStr,radix: 16));
  return byteConvert.getFloat64(0);}
```

And demo :

```
double lat = parseHexString("0000004069665E40",true);
//lat = 121.60017395019531
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have:

```dart
int.parse("0xbf641dad")
```

I don't see why this wouldn't work:

```dart
int.parse("0xbf641dad").toDouble();
```

Comment: The hexadecimal bytes presumably represent the bytes of an IEEE-754 floating-point number, not the bytes of an integer value.

Answer (score 0):

I used dart:typed_data for this:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

List<int> intList = [191, 100, 29, 173];
double asFloat = ByteData.view(Uint8List.fromList(List.from(intList)).buffer).getFloat32(0, Endian.little);
```

Library reference: https://api.dart.dev/be/136883/dart-typed_data/dart-typed_data-library.html