# Initialize a double with a 64-bit hex literal integer for its bit-pattern, like a compiler uses in asm

Tags: c++, assembly, floating-point, constants, type-punning

I have a small C++ 32-bit application with this variable assignment:

```cpp
double unknown = -4.656612875e-10;
```

I want to understand how this is represented in assembly. And apparently it's represented as `0xbe000000001c5f68` in xmm0.

To verify, I now add this line:

```cpp
double unknown1 = 0xbe000000001c5f68;
```

I was expecting it to result in the exact same assembly, but it is different.

```cpp
    double unknown = -4.656612875e-10;
004F2265  movsd       xmm0,mmword ptr [__real@be000000001c5f68 (04F9BE8h)]  
004F226D  movsd       mmword ptr [unknown],xmm0  
    double unknown1 = 0xbe000000001c5f68;
004F2272  movsd       xmm0,mmword ptr [__real@43e7c0000000038c (04F9B40h)]  
004F227A  movsd       mmword ptr [unknown1],xmm0
```

What hexdecimal value must I assign to `unknown1` so the assembly is equal to `unknown`?

Comment: `-0x1.00000001c5f68p-31` https://godbolt.org/z/hxvef1z7h

Comment: `-0x1.00000001c5f68p-31` is not a hexadecimal number. It doesn't answer my question. And why does my example not work?

Comment: *"...application with this variable assignment..."* That is not assignment but initialization.

Comment: Closed as a duplicate, although it is none. Why am I not surprised... SO at it's default.

Comment: @Daniel: Why do you think that the first comment is not a hex number.

Comment: It is a hexadecimal number, it's just a floating point one rather than an integer. Your example simply converts the integer to the double resulting in a different value

Comment: @Daniel: And the answer to your question is easy: If you have a double that does not represent an integer, no integer (independend of decimal or hex) can have the same value.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I think I understand. Is there a way in C++ to assign the hex value without conversion? Something like `double unknown1 = noconversion(0xbe000000001c5f68);` which results in `movsd       xmm0,mmword ptr [__real@be000000001c5f68 (04F9B40h)]`?

Comment: c++20 adds `std::bit_cast<double>(0xbe000000001c5f68LL)` though it generates exactly the same code: https://godbolt.org/z/37fPfM7b6

Comment: @AlanBirtles, that's what I need. Thanks!

Comment: The concept you're looking for is "type punning", in your case to use a 64-bit integer (from an integer literal; hex or otherwise) as the bit-pattern (object representation) for a `double`.  Before C++20, you'd do this with `memcpy` to copy the bytes.  Assignment / initialization with `=` has an implicit conversion, like a cast such as `(double)123` which produces a double that represents that number, rather than a double with that small integer as its bit-pattern.  Using a larger number doesn't make it different.

Comment: @AlanBirtles: That duplicate isn't very good for this question.  They want to give the whole IEEE binary64 bit-pattern as a single 64-bit integer, not split into sign / exponent / mantissa components, and that duplicate doesn't provide a way to do that.  Presumably there is a duplicate about type-punning vs. initialization, though.  A question like this for another language ([Parsing integer bit-patterns as IEEE 754 floats in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55355482)) has some upvotes, and mentions Java's `intBitsToFloat` special case of a type-pun, so I'll reopen if there's no exact dup.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Certainly the `LL` in `std::bit_cast<double>(0xbe000000001c5f68LL)` is not needed -  somewhat [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#WET).

Answer (score 3):

`0xbe000000001c5f68` is the same as the integer literal `13690942867208167272`, so your `unknown1` is initialized to that value (which is nowhere near `-4e10`, it is on the order of `1e19`).

What you see in the assembly is that `-4.656612875e-10` has an object representation of the same eight bytes as `0xbe000000001c5f68` (`BE 00 00 00 00 1C 5F 68`). You can convert type while keeping the object representation with [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) to reinterpret the bits:

```cpp
double unknown1 = std::bit_cast<double>(0xbe000000001c5f68u);
```

In general, this is called "type punning": keeping the object representation unchanged.  Normal conversions and casts keep the value represented the same, or as close as possible (e.g. truncating a double to an integer, or rounding a huge integer to the nearest representable double).

Without C++20, the portable way to type-pun is with
`memcpy(&foo_double, &foo_u64, sizeof(foo_double));`

---

There are also hexadecimal floating point literals, which would look like:

```cpp
double unknown2 = -0x1.00000001c5f68p-31;
```

But it doesn't match one-to-one with the object representation.  You can see the mantissa field is there literally in hex, but the first 12 bits ([sign and exponent fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64)) of the binary64 are `(e + 1023) | (negative ? 0x800 : 0)`. For this number, `(-31 + 1023) | 0x800 == 0xbe0`, the first 3 hexadecimal digits.